# The kinetic energy of rotation of a rigid body in generalized coordinates with Einstein notation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, coordinate-systems, rigid-body-dynamics

The kinetic energy of rotation of a rigid body is given by:

[image]

Write T in generalized coordinates in the form:

[image]

Determine the explicit form of [image]

I opened the cross product with the civita levi symbol and the dot product with the product of the levi symbols, but I can't get the requested answer

Comment: The product of two Levi-Civita symbols can be expressed in terms of Kronecker deltas.